How to debug memory usage by collator?
I was wondering what would be the best way to debug the memory usage by a collator? I started a new collator for an existing polkadot parachain, it is currently syncing and sometimes the memory spikes up to 60GB, what could be the cause?
The strange thing is that I have an existing collator for the same chain that is running in a machine with 16GB without any issues.
